# Sorted container of pointers to custom types based on a non-unique priority value, as a class member

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++17, std

I need a container that meets this scenario:

1. Needs to be a member of a class
2. Needs to contain pointers to a custom type
3. The elements are sorted using a non-unique priority value (an integer. for example: priority 0 items go before priority 1 items, before priority 2 items. Order between items of the same priority is non-important)
4. Cannot use boost or any other external library

Optionally , it would be really good if I don't have to create an additional class/struct to support sorting. Also, up to C++17 is good.

Note, I am using (`auto item : collection`), but if this only works with traditional iterators, that is also fine.

So for example:

```
class MyBigClass {

   Collection<Item*> myItems;
   void MyMain();
}

class Item {
   std::string data;
   int priority;
}


void MyBigClass::MyMain()
{
  Item i1("data1", 1);
  Item i2("data2", 0);
  Item i3("data3", 3);
  Item i4("data4", 1);
  myItems.insert(&i3);
  myItems.insert(&i1);
  myItems.insert(&i2);
  myItems.insert(&i4);
  
  for(auto item : myItems) {
     cout << item->data << endl;
  }

}


// expected output
// data2
// data1
// data4
// data3
```

I was hoping I could use a Set, but its associativeness is giving me trouble since my comparison function works with ordering, but not with uniqueness (for the set membership). I guess I could use a vector and order after every insert, but there may be something better I could do. As far as I can tell there is no non-associative sorted container.

Comment: Do you need sorted iteration, or just priority access to the highest priority? If it's the latter, have you considered [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? Your example has a `for` loop, so I'm assuming the former though

Comment: Yes, sorted iteration. Insertions are done mostly once per item at the beginning of the program, and iterations are extremely common.
That's why I was also considering a vector that is sorted on insertion, but my concern was startup time.

Comment: Are your priority values dense, and possibly even bounded? Like, can you guarantee the values are between, say, `[0...5]` or something? If so, you might have the best luck with either an array of vectors, or a vector-of-vectors. You would need some custom logic for a single iteration, but this would give you dense contiguous traversal of objects which will be fast. However, this really only works well if you know that you won't have many spaces between priorities. At which point the "priority" becomes the index to the outer container (array or vector)

Comment: I don't quite follow how a vector of vectors or an array of vectors would work here?
Are you suggesting a vector per priority?
Initially, yes, I would be able to bound them to three (high, default and low), but for some corner cases we may need more, maybe not many more. It is definitely worth considering.
Thanks!

Comment: _"Are you suggesting a vector per priority?"_ -- yeah, exactly. If you know the priorities are bounded and dense (e.g. you won't have arbitrary numbers with large gaps between them), then you have a really easy way to store all elements contiguously per priority. This generally makes iteration faster thanks to better cache-locality (especially compared to node-based iteration like `set`s, which thrash your cache). Iteration is also reasonably easy, since you iterate highest-to-lowest priority, and through each subcontainer

Comment: If I am storing pointers (rather than values), would cache-locality still be relevant in this case?
Pondering... if the number of priorities is flexible, but known to be small for any given run, would a map<int, vector<Item>> make sense then?

Comment: I think the answer there is, _it depends_ -- but it still likely could benefit. You will still have a potential cache-miss on the pointer, as you mentioned, but `vector`s can at least save on cache misses per iteration (which you would hit with any node-based data-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::multiset` with a custom *compare* function will suffice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct Item {
   std::string data;
   int priority;
};

struct item_compare
{
    bool operator()(Item* lhs, Item* rhs)
    {
        return lhs->priority < rhs->priority;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::multiset<Item*, item_compare> item_set;
    Item i1{"data1", 1};
    Item i2{"data2", 0};
    Item i3{"data3", 3};
    Item i4{"data4", 0};
    Item i5{"data5", 0};
    
    item_set.insert(&i1);
    item_set.insert(&i2);
    item_set.insert(&i3);
    item_set.insert(&i4);
    item_set.insert(&i5);

    for(auto item : item_set)
       std::cout << item->data << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Live example:  https://ideone.com/iY9Jrp

Comment: Seems multiset is what the OP wanted.

Comment: The question explicitly states "non-unique" priorities. This will not work with multiple priorities of the same value. You would require, at the least, a `std::multiset` for the logic OP described to work.

Comment: @Chad According to the history, the title of the question was always "Sorted container of pointers to custom types based on a non-unique priority value, as a class member"?

Comment: LOL, maybe I just can't read.  Anyway, example and answer both updated.

Comment: I haven't used multiset much. Is there a perf or memory drawback compared to the set? Would this still be better than using a vector and sorting on insert?

Comment: Yeah, seems I jumped the gun on it as the question _always_ stated that `set` wasn't appropriate.  Apols all!

Comment: @cloudraven Whatever drawbacks there may be over `std::set`, if this meets your requirements you're either stuck with it or rolling your own very similar version.

Comment: I think it's better to use smart pointers here. The lifetime management may be complex if we only store raw pointers in containers.

Comment: "Would this still be better than using a vector and sorting on insert?" it depends of usage. `std::vector` would have linear memory but inserting/removing in middle or begining would require movement.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Agree 100% on smart pointers.  In this contrived example there is no _ownership_ in the multiset.

Comment: All Items are owned by other objects that are longer lived than mybigclass. In the scenario I have ownership is fortunately not an issue. Think of mybigclass as a directory of other things living in the system

Comment: Following up on this solution. If some of my keys need to change priority, is this still the best way to go?
I am finding that I need to remove the key, change the value, and then reinsert it (in that precise order or it doesn't work), which seems prone to cause bugs.